# How do I put a tree map with keys and values sorted into an ascending list?

Tags: java, list, treemap

So this program gives the occcurences of each word. I need to make a list with this data sorting these words in ascending order.

```
import java.util.*;

public class A1E5{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Set text in a string
    String text = "Good morning. Have a good class. " +
      "Have a good visit. Have fun!";

    // Create a TreeMap to hold words as key and count as value
    Map<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();

    String[] words = text.split("[\\s+\\p{P}]");
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
      String key = words[i].toLowerCase();

      if (key.length() > 0) {
        if (!map.containsKey(key)) {
          map.put(key, 1);
        }
        else {
          int value = map.get(key);
          value++;
          map.put(key, value);
        }
      }
    }

    // Display key and value for each entry
    map.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + "\t" + v));
  }
}
```

Comment: Expected input/output?

Comment: Ordering by what? The word? Your code already does that.

Answer (score 0):

Implement Comparator interface and override its compare method in java.
Obtain map.entrySet() in set, convert it into list (we have converted set to list because Collections’s sort method can accept only list type as parameter).
Call Collections.sort and pass list [i.e. listOfentrySet] as parameter.
Collections.sort internally calls Arrays.sort, Arrays.Sort() internally calls Merge Sort.Merge sort calls overridden compare method of Comparator interface for comparison of keys.Ultimately listOfentrySet will contain entry (key-value) pairs sorted on basis of keys in java.

Its a simple google search but here you are:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;



class SortByKeyAscending implements Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>>{

@Override
public int compare( Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> entry1, Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> entry2){
    return (entry1.getKey()).compareTo( entry2.getKey() );
    }
}



public class SortMapByKeyAscendingExample {

public static void main(String...a){
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    map.put(4, 1);
    map.put(2, 1);
    map.put(3, 1);
    map.put(5, 1);

    Set<Entry<Integer, Integer>> entrySet = map.entrySet();
    List<Entry<Integer, Integer>> listOfentrySet = new ArrayList<Entry<Integer, Integer>>(entrySet);

    System.out.print("Before sorting by key : ");
    for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry:listOfentrySet){
     System.out.print(entry.getKey()+"="+entry.getValue()+"  ");
    }

    Collections.sort(listOfentrySet, new SortByKeyAscending());


    System.out.print("\nAfter sorting by key(ascending): ");
    for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry:listOfentrySet)
     System.out.print(entry.getKey()+"="+entry.getValue()+"  ");


   }
}
```

The output would be (key value)

Before sorting : 4=1  2=1  3=1  5=1

After sorting : 2=1  3=1  4=1  5=1

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your requirement correctly, since you can't have a TreeMap itself sort on the values you want something like this:

```
List<String> wordsList = new ArrayList<String>();
map.forEach((k, v) -> wordsList.add(k));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(wordsList.toArray()));
```

**Output:**

```
[a, class, fun, good, have, morning, visit]
```

Or this:

```
List<String> wordsList = new ArrayList<String>();
for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
  String key = entry.getKey();
  for(int i = 0 ; i <= entry.getValue(); i++) {
    wordsList.add(key);
  } 
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(wordsList.toArray()));
```

**Output:**

```
[a, a, a, class, class, fun, fun, good, good, good, good, have, have, have, have, morning, morning, visit, visit]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to print out the results ordered by count, you can do this:

```
map.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
        .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey() + "\t" + e.getValue()));
```

You can also use streams to produce your frequency map in the first place:

```
Pattern.compile("[\\s+\\p{P}]")
        .splitAsStream(text)
        .map(String::toLowerCase)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
        .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey() + "\t" + e.getValue()));
```

Comment: The OP is ambiguous on what he wants the words sorted by but correct me if I am wrong, does he not say he want the output as a list?

Comment: @shash678 If so, he made no attempt at doing that. My interpretation is that he wanted to print them as a list.